# Symfony2 Firewall configuration issue

Tags: symfony

I've got a security configuration issue.

I want to create multiple firewalls with different authentication processes.

I use a OAuth authentication with FOSAuthServer and I want to add one more for another service.

Here my `security.yml`:

```
freshdesk:
        pattern: ^/freshdesk/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            check_path: app_freshdesk_login_check
            login_path: app_freshdesk_login
            success_handler: app.freshdesk_authentification_success_handler
        logout:
            path: fos_user_security_logout
            target: /
        anonymous: true

    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            check_path: app_oauth_server_auth_login_check
            login_path: app_oauth_server_auth_login
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
        logout:
            path: fos_user_security_logout
            target: /
            success_handler: app.logout_handler
        anonymous:    true
```

My problem is, when I login with the freshdesk login form, I am redirected to `login_check` but it returns a blank page. I have concluded that sf2 is not intercepting my authentication request, but I don't know why.

Has anyone got a idea or had the same problem?

Comment: What happens if you only define the `freshdesk` firewall? Does it work then? This awfully reminds me of a bug within `Doctrine`: http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-3120

Comment: I found the solution, the problem was i use jms routing and the freshdesk doesn't match